# c++11 for_each with lambda as member function

Tags: c++11

I am facing the compilation error when using lambda with member function in for_each loop. please the below code snippet for reference.

```
void CCommConfig::AddAllowedIP(const string& strIp)
{
if (!strIp.empty())
m_allowedIpsList.push_back(strIp);
}
void CCommConfig::AddAllowedIpList(STRING_LIST &lstIps)
{
std::for_each(begin(lstIps), end(lstIps), this->AddAllowedIP);
}
```

Errors listed as

> 1>........\Source\Lib\cci\src\CommConfig.cpp(70): error C3867:
>   'CCommConfig::AddAllowedIP': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a
>   pointer to member 1>........\Source\Lib\cci\src\CommConfig.cpp(70):
>   error C2672: 'std::for_each': no matching overloaded function found

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `this->AddAllowedIP` to get a function object to call `CCommConfig::AddAllowedIP` with `this`, that is simply not allowed. You can get a pointer to the function via `&CCommConfig::AddAllowedIP` but that doesn't help you because it needs a `CCommConfig` to call it from.

You should create a lambda:

```
[this](const string& ip){ this->AddAllowedIP(ip); }
```

or you can use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) (though it's fallen out of favor):

```
std::bind(&CCommConfig::AddAllowedIP, this, std::placeholders::_1)
```

Both will create a function object that will properly call `AddAllowedIP` with `this` on your behalf so you can pass it to `for_each`.

**Edit:** looking at it again, you might just be better off with a loop:

```
for (const string& ip : lstIps)
  AddAllowedIP(ip);
```